# pugixml: find out whether xpath matches a particular node/attribute

Tags: c++, xpath, pugixml

Given an `xpath_query` and an `xml_attribute` or `xml_node`, I want to know whether that attribute or node would be matched by the query.

I could evaluate the query to an `xpath_node_set` and then check whether the node is inside like this:

```
bool match(const pugi::xpath_query& query, const pugi::xml_node& node)
{
    for (const auto& child : query.evaluate_node_set(node.parent()))
    {
        if (child.node() == node)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

However, that seems a little costly. Is there a cheaper way?

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
 count(expressionSelectingTheNode | theQuery) = count(theQuery)
```

where you need to substitute above "expressionSelectingTheNode " and "theQuery" with the correct expressions.

This returns `true()` if and only if the single node selected by the expression `expressionSelectingTheNode` is one of the nodes selected by the expression `theQuery`.

**Example**:

If we have this XML document:

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

**And the node is** (selected by `/*/num[. = 6]`):

```
  <num>06</num>
```

**and the expression is** (selects all `num` elements whose value is both multiple of 2 and multiple of 3):

```
/*/num[. mod 2 = 0 and . mod 3 = 0]
```

**Then we evaluate this expression**:

```
   count(/*/num[. = 6] | /*/num[. mod 2 = 0 and . mod 3 = 0])
  =
   count(//*/num[. mod 2 = 0 and . mod 3 = 0])
```

**and the result is `true()`.**

If we evaluate this expression (wanting to see if `<num>05</num>` is also selected):

```
   count(/*/num[. = 5] | /*/num[. mod 2 = 0 and . mod 3 = 0])
  =
   count(//*/num[. mod 2 = 0 and . mod 3 = 0])
```

the result is now `false()` .